# Get Multiple Attribute (Src) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, return-value, attr

Currently, my code is only returning the first value. I need to return all the values using loop because the numbers of li's changes from time to time. How can I do this?

```
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
        <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="vid06"><img
 src="img/box6.jpg" height="100%" width="100%">
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="vid07"><img
 src="img/box7.jpg" height="100%" width="100%">
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="vid08"><img
 src="img/box8.jpg" height="100%" width="100%">
        </li>
        <li class="ui-state-highlight" id="vid09"><img
 src="img/box9.jpg" height="100%" width="100%">
        </li>
      </ul>
      <input id="submit" value="submit" type="button">

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submit").click(function(){
var srcimg = $("#sortable2 img").attr('src');
alert( 'You have selected: '+ srcimg);
});
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to iterate through each one, and build up the array as you go:

```
var src = [];
var srcimg = $("#sortable2 img").each(function() { src.push($(this).attr('src')) });
srcimg = src.join(', ');
```